# Odata filter query Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'datetime'

Tags: odata, power-automate

I'm trying to execute a SQL query in Power Automate flow using OData query language. Here's my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
    column_name_1, 
    column_name_2, 
    column_name_3
FROM 
    table_name
WHERE 
    CAST(Transaction_Date AS DATE) >= DATEADD(day, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    AND CAST(Amount_in_USD AS FLOAT) >= 10000
    AND TYPE_OF_TRANSACTION = 'PURCHASE'
    AND Transaction_Country = 'US';
```

Note: The data in the "Transaction_Date" column looks like '2024-03-21'.

Below is how I translated it into OData:

**Filter query:**

```
Transaction_Date ge datetime'2024-03-03T00:00:00Z' 
and Amount_in_USD ge 10000 
and TYPE_OF_TRANSACTION eq 'PURCHASE' 
and Transaction_Country eq 'US'
```

**Select query:**

```
column_name_1, column_name_2, column_name_3
```

However, when I run this, I keep getting an error message:

```
Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'datetime'2024-03-03T00:00:00Z'' at '31' in 'Transaction_Date ge datetime'2024-03-03T00:00:00Z' and Amount_in_USD ge 10000 and TYPE_OF_TRANSACTION eq 'PURCHASE' and Transaction_Country eq 'US''.

     inner exception: Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'datetime'2024-03-03T00:00:00Z'' at '31' in 'Transaction_Date ge datetime'2024-03-03T00:00:00Z' and Amount_in_USD ge 10000 and TYPE_OF_TRANSACTION eq 'PURCHASE' and Transaction_Country eq 'US''.
clientRequestId: dde40166-d0e8-4e45-b63e-7ee37afe38ba
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

My flow looks like this:

[image]

The details of query looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the step in your flow where you’re doing this because the standard SQL connector doesn’t work like that in my experience.

Comment: Sure! I start by adding a recurrence as a trigger point because I want this flow to execute daily. Second, I add an "Execute a SQL query" action and type in the code I posted previously. Followed by a "for each" loop and then a "condition" action. I have added "Send an email (v2)" for both the true and false conditions.

Comment: Add a screenshot, easier

Comment: I wanted the configuration for the specific SQL step given that’s what your issue is with. Show that if you can please.

Comment: Hi @Skin , thanks for specifying, added already.

Comment: That looks like it may be the V1 action.  You should now be able to call a query and simply specify the query string as you would in a desktop tool like SSMS.  My suggestion, remove your action and add it back and make sure it's the v2 version of the connector.  Not sure how you got to where you are with that version TBH.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, what do you mean about v1/v2?

Comment: When I add the "Execute SQL Query" action for SQL Server, I don't get the OData options, I simply add in a fully qualified query as you would run in SSMS, this is the doco ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#execute-a-sql-query-(v2) ... and this is a screenshot of that action ... https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/301016iDF1F12E45C8F1935?v=v2

Comment: Oh my god, now I see the problem. I've been using Odata to do this but now I know I could just use my original query! My problem has been solved all because of you, thanks!

So what I've tried is to input the query I wrote and set up the condition. Thank you so much for assisting me!